# Gathering data from three separate tables, sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have three separate tables that represent student attendance for three weeks, respectively. I want to be able to generate four columns that break down the attendance by week for each of the students. If a student was present multiple times a week, the number of times present should be added. Also, if a student was present in one week and not the next, it would get 1 for the month present (assuming it was only present once) and and 0 for the one absent. I have tried to multiple variations of count() and joins but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The following is a truncated fiddle:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b847a

Here is a sample of what I am trying to achive:

`Name  |  CurrWeek |  LastWeek | TwoWkAgo`

`Paula |     0     |      2    |    3`

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? You have tagged both, but these are different products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than three tables you should have only one with a column for the week. So naturally one solution for your request is to build it on-the-fly with `UNION ALL`:

```
select
  name,
  sum(week = 'currentWeek') as currentWeek,
  sum(week = 'lastWeek') as lastWeek,
  sum(week = 'thirdWeek') as thirdWeek
from
(
  select 'currentWeek' as week, name from currentWeek
  union all
  select 'lastWeek' as week, name from lastWeek
  union all
  select 'thirdWeek' as week, name from thirdWeek
) all_weeks
group by name
order by name;
```

(If you want to join the three tables instead, you'd need full outer joins, which MySQL does not support, if I remember correctly. Anyway, my advice is to change the data model.)

Comment: Thanks, when I use this, I get the following error:
`Incorrect string ' for column 'vret' at row 1`
Any suggestions as to why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
select currweek.name, currweek.att, lastweek.att, twoWkAgo.att from 
(select name, count(attendance) as att from currentWeekTable group by name) currweek,
(select name, count(attendance) as att from lastWeekTable group by name) lastweek,
(select name, count(attendance) as att from twoWeekTable group by name) twoWkAgo
where twoWkAgo.name=currWeek.name and twoWkAgo.name=lastweek.name;
```

Assuming your 3 attendance tables contain name as common field.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  However, when I run this, I get the following error: Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You are using comma-separated joins, which were made redundant in 1992! Please don't use them. Then, what you are actually using is cross joins with where conditions, so essentially inner joins. But you need full outer joins here because you want to see results where a student only attended in one of the weeks, too. MiddleZ has provided a SQL fiddle, where you could have checked your query.